# node.js hello world server on amazon EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, node.js

As a lead in to deploying the [Ghost blogging platform](http://docs.ghost.org/installation/linux/), I am checking that node.js can be deployed on my Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu 13.04

The Ghost Github page even gives step by step instructions on how to [deploy to EC2](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Deploy-Ghost-to-EC2) and verifying `node` is an important step.

I put the node sever in `/var/www/index.js` and ran `node index.js` so it should be listening on port 8080

```js
require("http").createServer(function(request, response){
  response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I was unable to connect to: http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ with Chrome

At this point I backtracked and put in the following inbound TCP rules:

```
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   Delete
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0   Delete
8080 (HTTP*)0.0.0.0/0   Delete
```

---

**Good news** although `curl 127.0.0.1` gives:

```html
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

`curl 127.0.0.1:8080` gives `Hello World!`.

**Why can't I connect to node from my home computer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed the rules for the `default` EC2 Security group, which I naively assumed applied to all of my instances.

My instance is actually a member of `launch-wizard-3` security group.  Once I changed the permissions there, node.js worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide port in the address?

http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080